# How to use dplyr::filter inside purrr::map

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with several variables. I would like to get a list where each item is a variable of the data.frame filtered with a condition.

For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~ var1, ~ var2, ~ var3,
  4, 0, 0,
  2, 3, 1,
  0, 4, 0
  )
#    var1  var2  var3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4     0     0
# 2     2     3     1
# 3     0     4     0
```

And I want to get the list of the variable filtered >0

```
# $var1
# [1] 4 2
#
# $var2
# [1] 3 4
#
# $var3
# [1] 1
```

I tried several things but the closest I can get for now is something like

```
df %>% map(~filter(df, .>0))
```

and I would like to include a `dplyr::select` to get only the variable filtered. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks for help and sorry for bad English, I hope it's still understandable.

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through the `names`.  Note that `filter` expects a `data.frame/tbl_df`.  With `map`, we are looping through the columns and it is a `vector`.  So, in order to make `filter` work, `map` through the `names`, subset the column, apply the `filter` and `unlist`

```
map(names(df), ~ df %>% 
                  select(.x) %>%
                  filter(. >0) %>%
                  unlist(., use.names = FALSE))
```

---

Or with `split`

```
split.default(df, names(df)) %>%
            map(~  .x %>% 
                       filter(. > 0) %>%
                        pull(1))
```

NOTE: The OP's question is `How to use dplyr::filter inside purrr::map`

---

Other ways without using `dplyr::filter` are

```
map(df, ~ keep(.x, .x != 0))
```

Or

```
map(df, setdiff, 0)
```

Or

```
map(df, ~ discard(.x, .x == 0))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lapply(df, setdiff, 0)
#$var1
#[1] 4 2

#$var2
#[1] 3 4

#$var3
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Second solution is perfect. Thanks

Comment: @Haezer, welcome to SO. If you found this answer useful for you, you can: (1) up-vote it, (2)  and more important, except it :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr::map` we can do

```
purrr::map(df, ~.[.!= 0])

#$var1
#[1] 4 2

#$var2
#[1] 3 4

#$var3
#[1] 1
```

---

Base R approach with `lapply` could be

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[x!= 0])
```